# Slow Loading of Page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm getting JavaScript errors for all my links that contain JavaScript events. This is caused by the user trying to click on a link, and yet the JavaScript files have not been loaded yet.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any way of blocking the JavaScript events until all the JavaScript files are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

If the code for whatever you're doing is declared *above* the link (i.e. the place where the code is used) you should not have this problem.

I'm unsure how different browses will handle the order of loading if the JavaScript is in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript blocks natively. Just ensure that your scripts are loaded before your links, i.e. within the `head` tag.

The above should fix it, but you should look into [Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/)

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way of handling this is to hide the page content behind a `DIV` until the onLoad() event fires, then reveal it by hiding the `DIV`.

**Edited to add**

I see his problem as not being specifically about javascript, but the general problem of keeping the user from interacting with the page before it's loaded.

Comment: No offense here, but I've *never* heard of this being a "conventional" way of doing things.  This is a very bad solution to the problem IMO.

Comment: @sparkleshy: you may not like my answer, but it's not incorrect. I've done it many times, and I've seen **others** do it many times. Both of the other answers depend on getting your script blocks in before your links, which is not always possible.

Comment: @egrunin: I'd probably upvote this answer _if it answered the question_. But it doesn't answer the question -> it is not useful -> everyone should downvote it.